# How to experimentally calculate transconductance of an OTA?

Tags: transistors, analog, spice, transconductance, ota

How can I experimentally calculate the transconductance of an Operational Transconductance Amplifier given that I know the value of bias current ?

Comment: I guess you think that an OTA is defined by one exact circuit diagram repeated for every other OTA that has ever existed?

Comment: "experimentally calculate"? So you mean "measure"?